# one single app with different subdomains

Tags: php, redirect, subdomain, multiple-domains

I am looking for a solution for my project but I don't know if I chose a correct title for my question, so I should apologise everybody if it doesn't seem relevant somehow.

I have an application written by PHP which is like this: http://app.mysite.com.

What is happening in this app is that customers come and open an account for themselves. They will use this application to get in touch with their own clients in this way that they register their clients in this application and they can communicate with them. So it is somehow important that after their signup for the service, their company's name be shown in the address bar like this: http://TheirFrimName.mysite.com so their clients can identify that they are connecting to the correct path.

What I am looking for is to find a solution that I have only my application under app.mysite.com and when a client signs up, it creates a subdomain with their firm's name and then it redirects to my application path, but the address in address bar should remain with their subdomain address like TheirFirmName.mysite.com.

I don't want to stick to this idea, so if somebody has a better solution I appreciate if they want to share with me, otherwise, I humbly ask people who know how to perform what is in my mind.

Comment: Will all sub domain always use the sames files? or can mycompany.mysite.com and hiscompany.mysite.com have a different root     And also What is your os and webserver

Comment: well, exactly what i am looking for is that both my company.mysite.com and hiscomany.mysite.com are using same file which are on app.mysite.com, my web server is Bluehost and os is linux. the application is under php.

Comment: It won't work the way that you think it will. You will need to add the DNS entry as well as the VirtualHost entry in order for this to work properly and resolve across all browsers.

Comment: Do you have access to your apache config files? with the plan you have at bluehost ?  if you do you may be able to do it by adding virtual host, And a dns entry that will resolve any subdomain to your server ip.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, Well, actually I am looking for a solution to make this work. :)

Comment: @NicolasRacine, I have access to it, and I can create virtual host, but what I don't know, is the step of configuration and besides, it is very important that the address of http://hiscompany.mysite.com remains in the address bar till the end of session. If it does like this, can you give me some step by step instructions that how I can perform it?